# Error when trying to open excel in sharepoint 2016 using office online server

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, office-online-server

I am trying to open excel document in SharePoint 2016 using Office Online Server. I have installed and configured the Office Online Server on a separate server and configured the SharePoint to use the OOS.

I think the configuration is correct as I am able to view word documents in the browser.
When I try to view excel files, it shows blank files and there are some errors in the browser console.
The errors are

```
Redirects are not allowed for CORS preflight requests.

XMLHttpRequest: NEtwork Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

[image: Error Messages in the console]

[image]

There are no errors when I try to open a word document.
Let me know in case any other information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not coming from the office online server - this is the issue with Internet explorer. Try to open the file another browser like Chrome.

In Internet Explorer follow the below steps and try again:

Go to Internet Options -> Security Tab -> Custom Security Level > Miscellaneous >Access Data Sources Across Domains > click on **Enable** - save the changes and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Habibur, It seems to be an issue more related to browsers. Better test with other browsers and see if this issue continues. If this issue occurs for all your browser, you can try to reset the wopi binding.